# How can I add hyperlink to text while sharing screenshot to other app from a flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart

``` Future<void> captureAndShareScreenshot() async { `` // Hide the system UI overlay before capturing the screenshot ```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);`

```
// Update the UI to reflect the change
(context as Element).markNeedsBuild();

RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
    globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;

ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
final canvas = Canvas(recorder);

// Calculate the desired padding for the top and bottom
final double paddingTop = 150.0;
final double paddingBottom = 17.0;
final double paddingRight = 135.0;
final double paddingLeft = 135.0;

final double paddedWidth =
    image.width.toDouble() + paddingLeft + paddingRight;
final double paddedHeight =
    image.height.toDouble() + paddingTop + paddingBottom;

// Create a white background
final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.white;
canvas.drawRect(
  Rect.fromLTWH(
    0,
    0,
    paddedWidth,
    paddedHeight,
  ),
  paint,
);
```

`// Draw the captured image on the white background`
`final img = await decodeImageFromList(pngBytes);`
`canvas.drawImage(`
`img,`
`Offset(paddingLeft, paddingTop),`
`Paint(),`
`);`

```
final resultImg = await recorder.endRecording().toImage(
      image.width.toInt() + paddingLeft.toInt() + paddingRight.toInt(),
      image.height.toInt() +
          paddingTop.toInt() +
          paddingBottom.toInt() -
          230,
    );

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
int id = prefs.getInt("alarmId")!;

ByteData? resultByteData =
    await resultImg.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
Uint8List resultPngBytes = resultByteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final fileName =
    'Cloudmon Alarm-$id.png'; // Specify the desired screenshot name here
final file = await File('${tempDir.path}/$fileName').create();
await file.writeAsBytes(resultPngBytes);
await Share.shareXFiles(`your text`
  [XFile(file.path)],
  text: 'Alarm ID - $id',
  subject: 'Screenshot',
);

SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
    overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values);


(context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
```

`}`

`` I would like to add hyperlink to $id while sharing screenshot to other apps which navigates back    to the apllication` ```